Add chemfig figure in a title
I would like to be able to add a small chemfig image in a (sub)title but I have an error message: ! Use of \CF_chemfiga doesn't match its definition.
In my example, I would like to add the symbol of an alkene \chemfig{C=C}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\chemfig{C=C}


\section{Test \chemfig{C=C}}

\end{document}


Will you use hyperref in your real document?

yes i use it : I guess this can change the solution that some have proposed?

Use \protect.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Test}

\chemfig{C=C}

\section{Test \protect\chemfig{C=C}}

\end{document}



Given that you are using hyperref in your actual document, you can use \texorpdfstring to provide an alternative approximation or replacement of the formula for bookmarks:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Test}
\chemfig{C=C}

\section{Test \texorpdfstring{\protect\chemfig{C=C}}{alkene}}

\end{document}


Good advice. Thank you

This works, but will give problems with the toc:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
%\tableofcontents

\section{Test}
\chemfig{C=C}


\newsavebox{\mol}
\savebox{\mol}{\chemfig{C=C}}

\section{Test \usebox{\mol}}

\end{document}


